# How to distribute c++ library that have source and header in same folder

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a simple library, and for personal preference, I put `.cpp` files and `.h` files in same folder called `lib`

I know that If I seperate header and source files, I can distribute it by exporting folder with headers like `include` folder

Which folder should I export in this case?

Comment: The one with the header files. If that's not the answer, then I really don't understand your question...

Comment: Well, the simple answer is, you'd have to export the `lib` folder... but if the idea is to provide a set of headers and a compiled library with the implementation, then providing the source code isn't something you'd want to do, right? Seems like personal preference is getting in the way of the "proper" way to do this...

Comment: Are you intending to distribute the source or the binary version of your library?  Makes a _huge_ difference.

Comment: if you want to distribute your library the easiest way is to separate the headers in an 'include' folder and forget about your personal preferences. You can afford personal preferences when you don't interact with other people.

Comment: @MooingDuck I'm intending to distribute 'binary' version of library

Comment: @Yang sounds like you answered your own question. If you intend to distribute the binary version, then you need to separate the headers from the source. Plain as day.

Comment: *How* you separate header files from the source files doesn't really matter. Either put all public header files in a separate directory, which makes it easy, or just copy the public header files from the common directory. Or a mix of these.

Comment: @RyanJ Well, I was looking for way to distribute binary without adding folders, and Joachim 's explanation seems good. Is there any other ways commonly used?

Answer (score 1):

What does exporting means and how this procedure is done in your build system?

I would recommend having an `install` build step (e.g. in makefile or Visual Studio post-build instruction) that would

- copy the produced lib into an appropriate location, so that your user can link against
- copy all the header files (`*.h` or `*.hpp`) from your source folder to a new `include` folder where the user of your library will later include from.

When you do this, make sure the copy is either always performed, or at least when a change in the header files is detected. You don't want to end up scratching your head, looking for a bug because your deployed include files didn't update properly.